# AVRDUDE throws errors when attempting ISP with AVR Dragon

Tags: arduino, avrdude, isp

I've got an Arduino board that I'm trying to program via ISP with an AVR Dragon. I think I've got it all cabled up right (I made my own ISP cable by cutting up an old floppy ribbon cable), but when I attempt to connect avrdude I get the following errors:

```
sudo /usr/bin/avrdude -pm328p -c dragon_isp -v -v -v -v -P usb -B 1 -t

avrdude: Version 5.10, compiled on Jun 29 2010 at 03:44:14
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : usb
     Using Programmer              : dragon_isp
     Setting bit clk period        : 1.0
avrdude: stk500v2_dragon_isp_open()
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRBLDR, serno: 00A200007E77
avrdude: usbdev_open(): using read endpoint 0x82
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync()
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): Sending sign-on command:
avrdude: jtagmkII_send(): sending 1 bytes
avrdude: Sent: . [1b] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [0e] . [01] . [f3] . [97]
avrdude: jtagmkII_recv():
avrdude: usb_fill_buf(): usb_bulk_read() error No error
avrdude: jtagmkII_recv(): Timeout receiving packet
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): Sending sign-on command:
avrdude: jtagmkII_send(): sending 1 bytes
avrdude: usbdev_send(): wrote -19 out of 11 bytes, err = error submitting URB: No such device
avrdude: jtagmkII_send(): failed to send command to serial port
```

I've hooked the AVR Dragon to two different Arduinos, and they both have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Dragons have always had some problems - not that they're not great.  Start by making sure the firmware is up to date.  It can be updated in AVR Studio.  Then I'd make sure that your cable is correct (verify pin 1 goes to pin 1, pin 2 to pin 2, etc with a DMM) and after that ensure that you have pin 1 of the ISP headers hooked together.  Those things are easy to get the wrong orientation on.